# Why is my input so messed up in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am trying to make a command line mail application for Linux (though I'm developing on Xcode cause a VM uses a lot of power for my computer). I have two options in the main menu (where the user inputs a number to select). I use this after every input whether a simple can or a get line(can, stringName):

```
void clearCin() {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
```

That is why I am perplexed that I am getting all sorts of weird behavior with my input. Here's my code and a sample output (the end function is just a for loop that does cost << endl;):

**Code**

```
bool stdEmail() {

    string to, cc, bcc, subject, message;

    cout << "When entering email addresses, seperate multiple email addresses with a space";
    endl(2);

    cout << "To: ";
    getline(cin, to);
    clearCin();

    cout << "cc: ";
    getline(cin, cc);
    clearCin();

    cout << "bcc: ";
    getline(cin, bcc);
    clearCin();
    endl(1);

    cout << "Subject: ";
    getline(cin, subject);
    clearCin();
    endl(1);

    cout << "Now enter your message, when you're finished, type a period on a new line";
    endl(2);

    ofstream file;
    file.open("newMessage.txt", fstream::trunc);

    bool repeat = true;

    while (repeat) {
        getline(cin, message);
        clearCin();
        if (message == ".") {
            repeat = false;
        } else {
            file << message << endl;
        }
    }

    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

**Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------
Welcome to mark's Multi-Mail program

Main menu:
--------------------------------------------------
1. Send personalized emails to multiple recipients
2. Send a standard email
3. Exit the program
--------------------------------------------------
2

When entering email addresses, seperate multiple email addresses with a space

To: one@example.com two@example.com

cc: three@example.com

bcc: 


Subject: Thanks for your help!


Now enter your message, when you're finished, type a period on a new line

Here is a sample message
.

Now I am trying to get it out of taking the message which should have happened when I typed a .


.


Program ending Have a Nice Day

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Here is what shows up in newMessage.txt:**

Here is a sample message

Comment: What was the output you were expecting? It looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` discards a newline and getline completes when it reads a newline so you would have to press enter twice after typing your message for getline to read it and you would have to press enter twice after entering a '.' to end your loop.

Comment: I tried removing the clearCin() from the while loop and that worked. Thanks.